# Getting errors whenever dealing with null or NaN types when working on csv files with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to replace all the Country ISO codes to Full Country Names to keep everything consistent as part of cleaning some data. I managed to find the `pycountry` package, which helps a ton! There are some fields on the CSV file that are empty, which I believe is causing some issues when running my code below.

Also, an additional question, not sure if it's just me, but there are times when CSV reads empty files as null/NaN or simply empty. I don't really know what went wrong there, but if possible I would like to change all those empty cells into one "thing" or type for ease of filtering/dropping it out.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
#use pycountry to match the Nationalities as actual country names
import pycountry
list_alpha_2 = [i.alpha_2 for i in list(pycountry.countries)]
list_alpha_3 = [i.alpha_3 for i in list(pycountry.countries)]

def country_flag(df):
    if (len(df['Nationality'])==2 and df['Nationality'] in list_alpha_2):
        return pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=df['Nationality']).name
    elif (len(df['Nationality'])==3 and df['Nationality'] in list_alpha_3):
        return pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3=df['Nationality']).name
    elif (len(df['Nationality'])>3):
        return df['Nationality']
    else:
        return '#N/A'

df['Nationality']=df.apply(country_flag,axis =1)
df
```

I was expecting the result to be something like:

```
0   AF  100 Afghanistan

1           #N/A

2   AUS 140 Australia

3    Germany    400 Germany
```

The error message I am getting is

```py
TypeError: ("object of type 'float' has no len()", 'occurred at index 0')
```

Yet, there shouldn't be any float type values in the 'Nationality' column I am working on. I am guessing this is simply the empty/null/NaN values being considered a float type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is remove misisng values first by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
print (df)
  Nationality
0          AF
1         NaN
2         AUS
3     Germany

import pycountry
list_alpha_2 = [i.alpha_2 for i in list(pycountry.countries)]
list_alpha_3 = [i.alpha_3 for i in list(pycountry.countries)]

def country_flag(x):
    if (len(x)==2 and x in list_alpha_2):
        return pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=x).name
    elif (len(x)==3 and x in list_alpha_3):
        return pycountry.countries.get(alpha_3=x).name
    elif (len(x)>=3):
        return x
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Nationality'] = df['Nationality'].dropna().astype(str).apply(country_flag)
print (df)
   Nationality
0  Afghanistan
1          NaN
2    Australia
3      Germany
```

Comment: @MaxiHui - Can you check `df['Nationality'] = df['Nationality'].dropna().astype(str).apply(country_flag)` instead `df['Nationality'] = df['Nationality'].dropna().apply(country_flag)` ?

Comment: apologies! I just realised the reason for the error is that there were 2-3 rows of data where Nationality actually was an integer, and one in date format. Think your code would run well but just need to revise it to ignore those rows. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to watch out for is when pandas is reading from a data source and tries to automatically assign a data type to a column, it will sometimes assign a different data type than what you would expect depending upon if there are empty values or not in the data source.

A classical example is integer values that are converted to float values.

If you have a CSV file with this exact content (note missing value in row 2 of column A):

```
ColA,ColB
0,2
,1
5,4
```

then reading the file with

```py
res_df=pandas.read_csv(filename)
```

will create a dataframe with floats in the column A and integers in the column B.
This is due to the fact that there is no canonical way to assign an "empty" value to an integer, whereas a float can just be set as NaN (not a number).

But if that value was present, you would get 2 columns of integers.

Just something to be aware of, as it may easily be forgotten, and then suddenly you are getting floats instead of integers in your code and be confused about it.